# 4.0 remove_filter for Wordpress core function not working for me

Tags: filters

I was trying to overwrite how captions are embedded into a page when editing in the admin. I simply did this:

```
 remove_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'image_add_caption', 20);
 add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'update_image_add_caption', 10, 8 );
```

But it's just not working. I have tried different variations of priorities, and not using them at all, but it doesn't work. Why wouldn't this work?

**UPDATE**

Here's what I am trying right now, but `$result` always returns false, so the filter isn't removed.

```
function childtheme_remove_filters(){
    $result = remove_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'image_add_caption', 20);
    add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'update_image_add_caption', 20, 8 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'childtheme_remove_filters' );
```

Comment: you probably do the remove too early, what is the return value of the remove? should be true if a filter was removed.

Comment: Its always false. I just placed the code above in my theme's function.php. I can tell it's happening too soon, so how can I make the remove come after the add filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments the `remove_filter` is called too early before the core `add_filter` is called. Best way to avoid this is to always remove nd add your filter at the init action

```
add_action('init','wpse163434_init');

function wpse163434_init() {
  remove_filter.....
  add_filter.....
}
```

This way you are assure that the core had finished initializing and all the core actions and filters are already set.

**Update:** all of the above is nice and true, but there is no software without bugs and apparently some filters are added in places where it is really hard to remove them without feeling it is too much off a hack, and `image_send_to_editor` is one of them.

Luckily that filter applies the `image_add_caption_shortcode` filter and passes the original html to it so instead of removing `image_send_to_editor` you might get the same impact by using the `image_add_caption_shortcode` filter.

Comment: I tried it in the init function, but it still returns false. Updating original question.

Comment: this time you removed the priority, IIRC you have to have it to the correct value

Comment: OK I am traveling right now. I will try it when I get back and report results. I thought I had the same priority value when removing ( wordpress gives it a 20), but can't recall. I will double check Friday. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the original post with what I have executing now. But it still tries to remove the filter before it has been added.

Comment: hmm, more complex then thought, updated the answer

Comment: For my purposes, this will work since I am just trying to remove the height & width properties. The short code for caption is already created by the time it reaches the `image_add_caption_shortcode` filter. I can preg_replace on the $shcode string that's returned. Do you know at what stage of loading this `image_send_to_editor` filter is being loaded? Or what needs hacking in order to make it work?

Comment: the media.php file in which it is added is loaded from the wp_editor function. In theory you can hook on a later filter which is being used there to remove it but then you will depend on order of execution which doesn't logically have to remain the same in future versions of WP

Comment: I figured there might be an issue with the way this filter was loaded. I might point it out to the WP guys to see if it's something that needs to be fixed. And thank you for pointing out I should look at the wp_editor function. I won't depend on a hack for or adjust core functionality. I'd like to just step through it to understand my problem better. But my specific issue has been resolved. thank you