# remove filter which calls a public static function

Tags: plugins, filters

I want to remove a filter which is added from within a public static function of a plugin class.

The filter is defined here (within the `WCSG_Cart` class, part of a plugin):

```
public static function init() {
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', __CLASS__ . '::add_gifting_option_cart', 1, 3 );
}
```

and the class is a singleton class - `WCSG_Cart::init()` is called immediately after the class is defined.

In my theme's `functions.php` file, I have

```
remove_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', array( WCSG_Cart::init(), 'WCSG_Cart::add_gifting_option_cart'), 99);
```

Which seems to make no difference.

As [per this post suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163464/4-0-remove-filter-for-wordpress-core-function-not-working-for-me), I have tried wrapping my `remove_filter` call in a function and adding it to the `init` action and that didn't work:

```
add_action('init', 'do_something', 99);
function do_something() {
  remove_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', array( WCSG_Cart::init(), 'WCSG_Cart::add_gifting_option_cart'), 99);
}
```

I have also tried using just the class name as a string (`'WCSG_Cart'`) in the array, and removing the `WCSG_Cart::` from the function name, to no avail.

I can't find any examples online of using `remove_filter` on a function that uses the `__CLASS__` variable.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remove_filter` is supposed to be called with the same priority as the `add_filter`, so in this case you may want to replace `99` with `1, 3`

`remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', …, 1, 3 );`

Comment: brilliant - that did the trick. Just for reference - I didn't need to wait for `init` to run, or use the `WCSG_Cart::` prefix in the call: `remove_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', array( 'WCSG_Cart', 'add_gifting_option_cart'), 1,3);`